# Understading for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Yesterday i have started courses on W3Schools. I am a little confused about one for loop in JavaScript.

```
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

It gives the following output:

> The number is 0
>
> The number is 1
>
> The number is 2
>
> The number is 3
>
> The number is 4

What I am little confused is:

The text value it's updated with every iteration, so,
after first iteration:

> The number is 0

As text = The number is 0

Then are the next ones, and I can't understand why it prints out "the number is 1" and so on, instead of

> The number is 0 The number is 1
>
> The number is 0 The number is 1 The number is 2
>
> The number is 0 The number is 1 The number is 2 The number is 3
>
> The number is 0 The number is 1 The number is 2 The number is 3 The number is 4

As with every next iteration the var text is updated and the for loop doesn't quit for loop to reset the value to var text = ""

Comment: The code you posted does not have any "output" at all. It just accumulates strings. What happens with `text` after that loop?

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

It is this task from [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for_ex)W3schools

//EDIT - doesn't matter anyways, I understood now :) :)

Comment: It's because of the + in `text +=`, it means "add to the previous value", remove it and `text`'s value will be overwritten by new content each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you accumulate the text inside a variable and then at the end print it.

If you watch the evolution of the `text` variable using a debugger you would see what you describe at the end.